# Have difficulty in understanding a BFS code

Tags: python, graph

```
def dfs(graph,start):
    path = []
    stack = [start]
    while stack != []:
        v = stack.pop()
        if v not in path:
            path.append(v)
        for w in reversed(graph[v]):
            if w not in path:
                stack.append(w)
    return path
```

The above node is about BFS using stack, can anyone help me figure out what does

```
for w in reversed(graph[v]):
```

mean? I couldn't quite understand, thank you.

Comment: are you coding a breadth-first search (BFS) or a depth-first search (DFS)?

Comment: it should be a DFS...there is a typo it the post, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w is all the edges of v, which is the next vertex we are going to search.
and then, in the inner loop, we appends those w that are not yet in the path to the stack.